# How do you get values from a dropdown list in Wicket?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I've found the following Wicket sample code:

```
package org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form;
import org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractReadOnlyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;

/**
 * Linked select boxes example
 * 
 * @author Igor Vaynberg (ivaynberg)
 */
public class ChoicePage extends BasePage
{
    private String selectedMake;

    private final Map<String, List<String>> modelsMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); // map:company->model

    /**
     * @return Currently selected make
     */
    public String getSelectedMake()
    {
        return selectedMake;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedMake
     *            The make that is currently selected
     */
    public void setSelectedMake(String selectedMake)
    {
        this.selectedMake = selectedMake;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public ChoicePage()
    {
        modelsMap.put("AUDI", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "A4", "A6", "TT" }));
        modelsMap.put("CADILLAC", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "CTS", "DTS", "ESCALADE", "SRX",
                "DEVILLE" }));
        modelsMap.put("FORD", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "CROWN", "ESCAPE", "EXPEDITION",
                "EXPLORER", "F-150" }));

        IModel<List<? extends String>> makeChoices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<? extends String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<String> getObject()
            {
                Set<String> keys = modelsMap.keySet();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(keys);
                return list;
            }

        };

        IModel<List<? extends String>> modelChoices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<? extends String>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<String> getObject()
            {
                List<String> models = modelsMap.get(selectedMake);
                if (models == null)
                {
                    models = Collections.emptyList();
                }
                return models;
            }

        };

        Form<?> form = new Form("form");
        add(form);

        final DropDownChoice<String> makes = new DropDownChoice<String>("makes",
            new PropertyModel<String>(this, "selectedMake"), makeChoices);

        final DropDownChoice<String> models = new DropDownChoice<String>("models",
            new Model<String>(), modelChoices);
        models.setOutputMarkupId(true);

        form.add(makes);
        form.add(models);

        makes.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange")
        {
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                target.addComponent(models);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class car{
      private String name;
      private String  model;

      public setname(String n){
           this.name=n;
      }
      public setModel(String m){
           this.model=m;
      }
      ///  and getters...
}
```

I want to create a `car` object in the sample code, and assign the values selected in the dropdown to the `car` object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the [`PropertyModel` class](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/PropertyModel.html). Wicket `PropertyModel`s can let you tie the value of a component directly to a value in your source. The Javadoc sample code is

```
Person person = getSomePerson();
add(new Label("myLabel", new PropertyModel(person, "name"));
```

When that label is added to the page, it'll display the value in `person.name` with no extra work on your end.

Your car sample code already uses `PropertyModel`s, so all you have to do is change the target. For example:

```
car theCar = new car();
final DropDownChoice<String> makes = new DropDownChoice<String>("makes",
        new PropertyModel<String>(theCar, "name"), makeChoices);
final DropDownChoice<String> models = new DropDownChoice<String>("models",
        new PropertyModel<String>(theCar, "model"), modelChoices);
```

This will set the value of `theCar.name` to what's in the makes dropdown list and the value of `theCar.model` to what's in the models dropdown list.

EDIT:
Yes, it's possible to set the values with a button instead of automatically. To do this, don't use the `PropertyModel`s. Instead, create a new Wicket `Button` object and override its `onSubmit()` method with code like

```
theCar.setName(makes.getValue());
theCar.setModel(models.getValue());
```

Or, if you want to do it AJAXically, put that inside an `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior`'s `onUpdate()` method.

Comment: i did what t u said like                                          aCar = new Car("","");                                           final DropDownChoice<String> makes = new DropDownChoice<String>("makes",
            new PropertyModel<String>(aCar, "name"), makeChoices);
          
        final DropDownChoice<String> models = new DropDownChoice<String>("models",
            new PropertyModel<String>(aCar,"model"), modelChoices);    and it does not work correctly

Comment: i get the selected car name by coding                                           aCar.setName(this.selectedMake);                                          but i dont know how to assign the model of the car

Comment: @ajdar, you shouldn't have to assign anything by hand. I'm testing now.

Comment: ok.Dement made me confused.Can i assign variables to my object using a button and how?

Comment: when i added      AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior() it gives me the error  Behavior can only be added to an instance of a RadioChoice/CheckboxChoice/RadioGroup/CheckGroup.

Comment: you said " Yes, it's possible to set the values with a button instead of automatically" .I want ajax to set the values automatically and button get the selected vaules.Is this possible?Thanks

Comment: @ajdar, I don't know, the original version still works for me in test. Did you change the code to reference `theCar.name` instead of `selectedMake`? I can post the entire source if you want. I don't understand your most recent comment; what do you mean by "get the selected values"?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use CompoundPropertyModel on form, on which you add DropDownChoice components.

If you would like to have DropDownChoice with divided areas, like "Ford", "Audi" etc.. you can use Wicket Select component, you can read about it here:  http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/select/Select.html .

And usually you can get value from DropDown using dropDownName.getModelObject() or dropDownName.getDefaultModelObject() methods. If it is not working, you should try to see, what

```
System.out.println("something: "+dropDownName.getModelObject());
```

shows, maybe there are problems with the model.

In case you use CompoundPropertyModel, you do not need to get value directly from DropDownChoice, but from CompoundPropertyModel, use something like:

```
model.getObject.getMakes();
```